# Manipulate the object creation of saved core data objects

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I'm pretty new to objective C and working on am existing project which uses core data (with the xcode template I think).

Some of our objects contain files, which are downloaded and converted to pdf by the app. We have error handling for failing httprequests and converting (which sets an error flag in the object) but when the app is closed (or crashed or whatever) during the downloading or converting (which runs async and parallel) I don't now how to set the error flag in may object.

My idea was to check for the necessary files for each object when they are load and created from the database. At which time would this be the best? Is there an delegate to manipulate the creation of the object or so I have to loop through all the object by myself?

Comment: Nope, based on what you've said you'll just have to loop through them. What might be an option is to write the file atomically in case of a crash, then when loading just check to see if the CoreData entities file is empty. Then you don't need a flag.

Answer (score 0):

There is not a delegate *per se* but there is a method that gets fired on the creation of a `NSManagedObject`.  Unfortunately that method exists on the `NSManagedObject` itself.  You can subclass `NSManagedObject` and then override `-awakeFromInsert` to provide behavior or change settings.  Make sure to call `super` first.